# I can not connect to ubuntu one from my netbook in my office

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, ubuntu-netbook

first sorry but my english is very bad. I have a problem, when I try to connect to ubuntu one, the application says same all time:

"La información no se puede recuperar. ¿Puede que su conexión a Internet esté caída?" "Error en la sincronización de archivos. (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED))"

I use ubuntu 11.04, in my office and at home. At home I updated from 9.04 to 11.04 and can connect whithout any problem. In my office I re-installed Ubuntu 11.04 and there I can not connect.

What does this happen? Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you behind a firewall or proxy in your office?
If so you will be unable to use Ubuntu One there as there is currently a bug that prevents Ubuntu one operating behind a proxy.

Seems a little silly I appreciate but more details are here:

[Launchpad bug](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/387308)